# Error while importing google contacts libraries?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, dependency-management

```
import atom.data
import gdata.data
import gdata.contacts.client
import gdata.contacts.data
```

while importing these libraries i got error:

```
    import atom.core
ImportError: No module named core
```

These libraries are installed correctly, shown in picture below.

[image]

What is the issue, why i am getting error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the error because you installed `atom` as a separate dependency. `gdata` included `atom` in [packages](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/blob/master/setup.py#L66) but not in requirements.

I will try to explain with an example. Activate a new `virtualenv`, install `gdata`:

```
pip install gdata==2.0.18
```

Your script works fine:

```
import atom.data
import gdata.data
import gdata.contacts.client
import gdata.contacts.data
```

Now let's check `atom` version: `pip show atom` (no data). Also you won't see `atom dist-info`. So, this is just a python package:

[image: packages]

Now let's install `atom` and check imports (`pip install atom==0.4.1 + import atom.data`). You'll see the error because previous `atom` and `atom==0.4.1` are different. And this is the main reason of error:

[image: packages2]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay thannx @Danila Ganchar . Can you tell me how to # Authorize the client for accessing google contacts api data.

Comment: @Rohit-Pandey sorry but I don't know nothing about `accessing google contacts api` etc. By the way the question refers only to the problem with _imports_. I'm sure you can find answer if you ask a new detailed question with necessary _tags_.

Comment: Okay Thanks brother @Danila Ganchar

Comment: Same Cap Brother.